# Using mmap for mapping memory

Tags: linux, memory

In linux kernel, i have the sequence for using mmap to map memory area like this:

```
1. mmap
2. mlock
3. munlock
```

My question is at step 3, should i need to call munmap or munlock or both of them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `mlock` and `munlock` are required to prevent the memory defined in the mmap from being paged to *swap*. If you look at `man 2 mlock` it is all explained rather well. `munlock` is required to reverse the lock. `munmap` obviously frees the region for other uses -- YES.

Comment: So do i need to call munmap?

Comment: Because i see in memtester source code, it calls to munlock function but doesn't call to munmap?

Comment: The region is *unmapped* automatically on program termination, so if you exit, NO, if your program continues and you no longer need the mapping, then YES.

Comment: Yes, thanks @DavidC.Rankin